# Disabling textfields on button click and simultaniously enabling another button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

*I would like to have:*

my Textfields `textInput` & `textInput2` and `btnClickMe` disabled
& `button2` enabled when i click on the button `Bevestig weddenschap`.

*I cannot figure out how to do this. Can you help me out?*

**XML code:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/details_frankrijk"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:id="@+id/tvDetails"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/positie"
    android:id="@+id/lblOutput"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDetails"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblOutput"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblOutput"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblOutput" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/bedrag"
    android:id="@+id/lblOutput2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInput2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblOutput2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblOutput2"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblOutput2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bevestig_weddenschap"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/plaatsbet"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDetails"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvDetails"
    android:onClick="btnClickMe" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/plaats_de_weddenschap"
    android:id="@+id/plaatsbet"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtInput2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/volgende"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:clickable="false" />
```

**Java Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweedescherm);
    TextView tvDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    //haal data van de intents en zet deze in de textview
    tvDetails.setText(i.getIntExtra("details", R.string.details_frankrijk));

}

public void btnClickMe (View v) {
    TextView tvDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
    EditText txtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    TextView lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
    EditText txtInput2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput2);

    lblOutput.setText("Het land " + tvDetails.getText().toString() + " haalt in het EK volgens jou positie " + txtInput.getText().toString() + ". Je hebt hiervoor " + txtInput2.getText().toString() + " euro ingezet.");

}
```

}

Comment: Use the `View.setEnabled(boolean)` for each of them

Comment: The link above answers for buttons, but it is the same for textviews, since the method used comes from the View class and the both inherit from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.setEnabled(false)` for the `EditText`s and `.setClickable(false)` for the `Button` and toggle the boolean when the `Button` *Bevestig weddenschap* is clicked

like

```
 txtInput.setEnabled(false);
 txtInput2.setEnabled(false);
 button.setEnabled(false);
```

and when the *Bevestig weddenschap* is clicked toggle the boolean by

```
 txtInput.setEnabled(true);
 txtInput2.setEnabled(true);
 button.setEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT** first wirte a custom function

```
 private void setDisableOrEnable(boolean flag) {
   txtInput.setEnabled(flag);
   txtInput2.setEnabled(flag);
   button.setEnabled(flag);
 }
```

first time on `onCreate()` call the function `setDisableOrEnable(false)` 
and on the *Bevestig weddenschap* button click call `setDisableOrEnable(true)`

and be sure `txtInput` , `txtInput2` and `button` is initialized befor calling the `setDisableOrEnable(false)` on `onCreate()`

So your `onCreate()` will look something like this.

```
  EditText txtInput;
  TextView lblOutput; 
  EditText txtInput2;
  TextView tvDetails;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweedescherm);
  tvDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
  txtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
  lblOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblOutput);
  txtInput2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput2);

  setDisableOrEnable(false);

  Intent i = getIntent();
  //haal data van de intents en zet deze in de textview
  tvDetails.setText("" + i.getIntExtra("details", R.string.details_frankrijk));

  }


public void btnClickMe (View v) {

    setDisableOrEnable(true);
    lblOutput.setText("Het land " + tvDetails.getText().toString() + " haalt in het EK volgens jou positie " + txtInput.getText().toString() + ". Je hebt hiervoor " + txtInput2.getText().toString() + " euro ingezet.");

 }

 private void setDisableOrEnable(boolean flag) {
   txtInput.setEnabled(flag);
   txtInput2.setEnabled(flag);
   button.setEnabled(flag);
 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Might as well use setEnabled for the button

Comment: could you tell me how to code the boolean? I'm so helpless trying to figure out what i'm doing wrong x.x

Comment: @NickyPloegman Please view my edited answer

Comment: @NickyPloegman have you tired the edited answer?

Comment: @NickyPloegman Please try this.. and let me know and possibly i have fixed a null pointer issue to the `tvDetails.setText()` . Please see edit

Answer (score 0):

For EditText use `editText.setEnabled(false);` in combination with `editText.setFocusable(false);`

For button only `button.setEnable(false)` will suffice.